# Codeigniter Ion Auth login view issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have installed `Ion_auth` with Codeigniter as user authentication library. I am facing an issue with `auth/login` view. If I enter `http://localhost/ciinstallation/auth/login`. I can still viewing `auth/login` page though my session has been registered. Everything works fine except above issue. My question is that - Why I can see the login page?

As a logged in user- I shouldn't see the login page anymore. What I am doing wrong?

Configuration Info as follows-

1. `Auth.php` includes `Auth` Controller extends CI_Controller
2. `Ion_auth_model` include `Ion_auth_model` extends CI_Model
3. Language configured properly
4. I loaded library @ autoload.php @ config directory.
5. Database connected properly (I can login). I can add new user.

I have tested by dumping logged in user information in welcome view. Data showing properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `auth` controller method `login` you should first check if you are currently logged in before showing the login form:

```
 if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        // Example: redirect them to the dashboard page
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
```

If you are logged in then you should be redirected to any Logged-in only page you want.